# "time" for instants or durations in science

Tags: terminology, time, science

I am trying to describe the evolution of a motion which is composed of smooth parts called "free flights" and instantaneous impacts. For example, consider a bouncing ball: its motion is a succession of free flights, separated with impacts (when the ball touches the ground).

I would like to refer to two time-related quantities: the duration of free flights, and the dates of impacts. The word "time" can refer to a length of time, or an instant (a date). To raise the ambiguity, I have chosen the following terminology:

- "free-flight durations" describes a length of time between two impacts;
- "impact times" describes the date of impact.

Is this correct and would "impact instants" or "impact dates" be better? I am open to other suggestions too, but I want to avoid "period" which I am already using to qualify repetitiveness.

Comment: I think you're fine.  Although I'd take the 's' off "free flight***s***"  It's just "free-flight durations" and then you can use TOIs or Times of Impact for a list of times.  A single time is just a Time of Impact.

Comment: @Jim. Thank you. I'll edit my question accordingly as I did not mean to add the "s". Out of curiosity, would "impact instants" have been correct?

Comment: "Duration" is Ok. If you record the events in a log or a database for further tracking, you may use the expression "impact timestamp" for the date and time at which an impact occurred,

Comment: Yes, duration or period. Time point or point in time or instant or moment.

Comment: I don't much like *duration*, which seems to me to suggest the *measure* of the period rather than period itself. *Period* and *instant* work better for me; or If you want to relate the two terms, you might consider *free-flight timespan* and *impact timepoint*.

Comment: I think these questions might find more accurate and useful answers on the Physics Stack Exchange site: http://physics.stackexchange.com Without further context, I am struggling to understand how "'free-flight durations'" could "describe a length of time between two *impacts,*" or how an "*instantaneous impact*" could "describe" a "date of impact." I think these might be issues in physics rather than issues in English Language & Usage. Best of luck in your quest for answers!

Comment: According to the [International Electrotechnical Vocabulary](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=113-01-13), "In common language, the word “time” is used with several different meanings. In technical language, however, more precise terms, e.g. date, duration, time interval should be used."

Comment: @StoneyB, in technical usage, *period* normally refers to the duration of each repetition of a periodic (repeating) behavior. For example, "the period of a sine wave" or "the orbital period [of a planet or moon]". In fields (like physics or engineering) where this usage is common, using *period* to describe a non-periodic event could be confusing.

Comment: @StoneyB- I actually interpreted OP’s question to be about durations. For example I might have expected something like “The complete flight consisted of 3 periods with free-flight durations of 1.5, 2.1, and 15.2 seconds respectively. Impacts occurred at  0:00:01.5, 00:00:3.6, and 00:00:18.8  ( with start of flight at 00:00:00)

Comment: @Jim: That's exactly it, you perfectly understood my question. I added an example (bouncing ball) to make it clearer.

Comment: @ThePhoton That's a very good point which I had not considered.

Answer (score 1):

*Interval*, mentioned in a comment, is indeed the technical word for a time span and is used both as an event and as a measure:

"The free-flight interval begins/began at 1:02:30."

"The free-flight interval is/was 4 seconds."  (No need to say "*lasts/lasted* 4 seconds.")

"The 4-second free-flight interval ends/ended at 1:02:34."